# Two css linked to a single html page causing overriding between element properties

Tags: html, css, nav

I have two css files
Say sidebar.css and topbar.css

When I link these in one html file, the properties get exchanged
Suppose if I specify the margin:0 to sidebar and margin:30px to topbar, the topbar gets placed at 0px too. And many other properties inside gets overridden etc. How should I overcome this and is there a way where I can link these codes in a html file individually without such problem? If not what changes should I make in the code.

I have a webpage containing nav elements and I've inserted a sidebar into the code which also consists some nav and other elements which makes alterations in my original webpage. When we link two css files ,how can we make 'em seperate and independent.

Here is my sidebar code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Sidebar Menu with sub-menu</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarnewstyle.css">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarnewstyle.css"/> <!-- href= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"-->
       </head>
       <body>
    
        
          <div class="btn">
             <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
          </div>
          <nav class="sidebar">
             <div class="text">
                Side Menu
             </div>
             <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#" class="feat-btn">RESULT
                   <span class="fas fa-caret-down first"></span>
                   </a>
                   <ul class="feat-show">
                      <li><a href="#">CSE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">ECE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
    
                <li>
                   <a href="#" class="serv-btn">Subject-wise
                   <span class="fas fa-caret-down second"></span>
                   </a>
                   <ul class="serv-show">
                      <li><a href="#">CSE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">ECE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subject</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="content">
             <div class="header">
               SYSTEM
            
          <script >
             $('.btn').click(function(){
               $(this).toggleClass("click");
               $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
             });
               $('.feat-btn').click(function(){
                 $('nav ul .feat-show').toggleClass("show");
                 $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
               });
               $('.serv-btn').click(function(){
                 $('nav ul .serv-show').toggleClass("show1");
                 $('nav ul .second').toggleClass("rotate");
               });
               $('nav ul li').click(function(){
                 $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
               });
          </script>
    
       </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the corresponding css file of sidebar

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      user-select: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .btn{
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      left: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      width: 45px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #1b1b1b;
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: left 0.4s ease;
    }
     .btn.click{
      left: 260px;
    }
     .btn span{
      color: white;
      font-size: 28px;
      line-height: 45px;
    }
     .btn.click span:before{
      content: '\f00d';
    }
     .sidebar{
      position: fixed;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      left: -250px;
      background: #1b1b1b;
      transition: left 0.4s ease;
    }
     .sidebar.show{
      left: 0px;
    }
     .sidebar .text{
      color: white;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 65px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #1e1e1e;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
     nav ul{
      background: #1b1b1b;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;
    }
    nav ul li{
      line-height: 60px;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    nav ul li:last-child{
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    }
    nav ul li a{
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      font-weight: 500;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    }
    nav ul li.active a{
      color: cyan;
      background: #1e1e1e;
      border-left-color: cyan;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover{
      background: #1e1e1e;
    }
    nav ul ul{
      position: static;
      display: none;
    }
    nav ul .feat-show.show{
      display: block;
    }
    nav ul .serv-show.show1{
      display: block;
    }
    nav ul ul li{
      line-height: 42px;
      border-top: none;
    }
    nav ul ul li a{
      font-size: 17px;
      color: #e6e6e6;
      padding-left: 80px;
    }
    nav ul li.active ul li a{
      color: #e6e6e6;
      background: #1b1b1b;
      border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    nav ul ul li a:hover{
      color: cyan!important;
      background: #1e1e1e!important;
    }
    nav ul li a span{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 20px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      font-size: 22px;
      transition: transform 0.4s;
    }
    nav ul li a span.rotate{
      transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
    }
    .content{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      color: #202020;
      z-index: -1;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .content .header{
      font-size: 45px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    .content p{
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
```

And this is a topbar which also has nav and other css elements in its style sheet resulting overlapping etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>NAv menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="topbarstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">I</a>
            <a href="#">II</a>
            <a href="#">III</a>
            <a href="#">IV</a>
            <div class="animation start-home">
                
            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the code of topbar stylesheet

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap')
    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background: #2c3e50; 
    }
    
    nav{
        position: relative;
        margin: 30px auto 0;
        width: 420px;
        height: 45px;
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
    }
    
    nav a{
        font-size: 15px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 45px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1; 
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    
    }
    nav .animation{
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        background: #4dff4d;
        border-radius: 8px; 
        transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    }
    
    a:nth-child(1){
        width: 100px;
    }
    
    nav .start-home,a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation{
        width: 100px;
        left: 0;
    
    }
    
    a:nth-child(2){
        width: 110px;
    }
    
    nav .start-II,a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation{
        width: 110px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    
    a:nth-child(3){
        width: 100px;
    }
    
    nav .start-III,a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation{
        width: 100px;
        left: 210px;
    }
    
    a:nth-child(4){
        width: 100px;
    }
    
    nav .start-IV,a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation{
        width: 120px;
        left: 300px;
    }
```

I've tried z-index and position as fixed / absolute. But is there no other way to link these stylesheets seperately in a single html file.

Answer (score 0):

When you link two css files, they are both loaded by the browser and interpreted as one big file, there is no way around it.

(note that this is how for instance css resets work: the first file will 'reset' all css to standardize it and then your css files come and are applied)

Since you have in both files a definition for `nav` the end result will be a combination of both definitions, with the last one taking precedence.

The only way I see around this is to actually use classes instead of elements as selectors.